# querying mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched google and on here and some info has been useful but mostly not so useful and still can't manage to query my database using php.
I'm very new to coding so thought it best to find an answer based on my code rather than other peoples slightly different problems. 
I have a small database, people fill in a form who wish to hire a bus. i have created a calendar and wish to print out for each day what time and for how long there is a hire, if there is one, based on the data people have entered which has been sent to my database.
The whole page shows but the calendar contains an error within its table saying:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2013-03-01' at line 1"

even if i delete the "where date=.." part of the query it continues to show this.
ive tried several different methods of writing the code out, including a loop and not including one but im not really sure what im meant to do.

EDIT: MY CODE IS NOW:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, length FROM hire WHERE date='01-03-13'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$Time = $row['TIME'];
$Length = $row['LENGTH'];

echo "Time: " . $TIME . "<br/>";
echo "Length: " . $LENGTH . "<br/>";


?>
```

I now get the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Users\Laura\Documents\COMPY\server\www\calendar.php on line 123"
It shows the page, calendar and "time" and "length" but with the error and no data

EDIT

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("busassociation", $con);                 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, length FROM hire WHERE date='01-03-13'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$time = $row['time'];
$length = $row['length'];

echo "time: " . $time . "<br/>";
echo "length: " . $length;

}
?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: try to restart your apache and mysql services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use backticks

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT `time`, `length` FROM `hire` WHERE `date`= '2013-03-01' ");
```

**EDIT.**

your are fetching your query two times.

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);   <------- delete this line

 while( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ){
```

**EDIT.2**

i think u dont reconize the diference between

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `mysql_fetch_row()`

if you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`  **it will be correct in your code.**

but if u use `mysql_fetch_row()` as u have done in your code u must echo values like that

```
 $Time = $row['1']; // suppose that `TIME` is the second column
 $Length = $row['2']; // suppose that `LENGTH` is the third column
```

**EDIT.3**

```
  <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
 mysql_select_db("your_db", $con);                  <---------replace by your database
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT time, length FROM hire WHERE date='01-03-13'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

 $Time = $row['time'];
 $Length = $row['length'];

 echo "Time: " . $Time . "<br/>";
 echo "Length: " . $Length . "<br/>";

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: MySQL permits `date` without backticks because so many people used it as a field name. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: thanks for replies, i restarted services, replaced my code and did what you said

$pdo = new PDO('localhost', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT `time`, `length` FROM hire WHERE `date`='2013-03-01");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['time']);
echo htmlentities($row['length']);


mysql_close($connect);
?>;

but i still get the same issue

Comment: the $row is beeing fetching the $result two times , so in the second can occur the problem. and the fetch error is always from the sql

Comment: Didnt LENGTH use to be a mysql built in function not so long ago? :)

Comment: @goodmood What problem can that cause? Be specific, or if you don't actually know what are you doing, don't post an answer, you may mislead somebody.

Comment: @HankyPanky I believe that still is a function :)

Comment: i stayed with my original code, changed my date format to varchar rather than date, and now have this:
"Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Users\Laura\Documents\COMPY\server\www\calendar.php on line 123"
i know i should use modern code but i know even less about that than the php code ive been using.

Comment: updated my answer . because u use row or fetch . in your code the row is wrong

Comment: if u have edited your code , please edit your question and paste your new code, maybe im talking in one way and u are in other way

Comment: u are missing select database function `mysql_select_db("your_db", $con);` and dont use `UPPERCASE` ur query contains `LOWERCASE` columns

Comment: ah okay no errors any more, thank you! but there is still no data being shown even though i have entered data into the table for the specified date

Comment: this is maybe about your `WHERE` clause , u have made wrong date. try remove `WHERE date='01-03-13'` and see if there is data.

Comment: oh it was due to capilisation. however, after entering another time and length on the same date, i can only show the first piece of data. is there a way to show more than one? if that makes sense

Comment: ok if u want more data , then fetch by while loop , look my edited answer number3, i have edited it

Comment: hmm i have changed my code to what you put however still only have one set of data for that date and the calendar layout has messed up :/

Comment: its about the date  . are u sure that this date have many data? try remove this `WHERE` clause and see.

Comment: i think im far too tired to be doing this, have been making incredibly silly mistakes. sorry to waste your time, but thank you very very much for the help!!